# Why aren't questions being closed?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions, review-queue, vote-to-close

In the past *month*, I have voted to close at least 10 identification questions, however, these still remain.

Is anyone actually looking at the close votes and reviewing them, or is this site now ruleless? Isn't part of the role of the moderators to check these review queues often?

Comment: Relevant https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an

Comment: Cheers @Dom, had no idea!